# how to have a <li> list hidden until the <ul> containing it is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have subgroups of li rows, contained in some ul lists. When the page opens all of the rows are displayed. I'd like it to have the li's hidden until the ul containing them is clicked.

I know you can use css "display:none" to have them hidden on page open, but being a beginner with javascript I'm not sure how to get the list to expand when its clicked.

Thanks

Comment: post code please

Answer (score 0):

I'd use toggle along with the `gt` selector to hide elements beyond a certain number.

```js
lis = $("li:gt(0)").hide();
$("ul").click(function () {
  lis.toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Expand</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like,

```
$('ul.subgroups').on('click',function(){ // will work only if you have at least a single li which is visible
   if ($(this).children('li:hidden').length) {
      $(this).children('li:hidden').show();
   }
});
```

Snippet,

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.subgroups').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).children('li:hidden').length) {
      $(this).children('li:hidden').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul class="subgroups">
      <li> Sub Item 2-1</li>
      <li style="display:none"> Sub Item 2-2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3
    <ul class="subgroups">
      <li> Sub Item 3-1</li>
      <li style="display:none"> Sub Item 3-2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `toggle` for this

```js
$('li a').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
})
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: block
}
li ul {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" title="">first</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">first</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">third</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">fourth</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" title="">second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="">third</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">first</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">third</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">fourth</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">fifth</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" title="">fourth</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" title="">fifth</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job perfectly. I tried using  <span> for the sub-group rows which worked too.